# Existing Service Providers in WSO2 IS 5.0.0 are not displayed in WSO2 IS 5.2.0 after upgrade

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of 2 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).

When I logged in the system through the admin console I noticed the already existing service providers are not displayed. I double checked the roles of the admin user and it had all the roles associated with the existing service providers and still I was not able to see them. Then I opened the database and took a look in the IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS and SP_APP and the service providers are there. I logged in the system again and tried to create service provider with name that already existed and receive correct error message.
However If I try to perform for example password grant type using the ClientID and ClientSecret of some of the "hidden" (old) Service Providers I am able to receive valid access token.

Is there a way to show these service providers? Is it related to some DB misconfiguration? I observed the behavior after the upgrade. This is causing me some troubles because in order to update the Claim configuration for some of these existing and "hidden" Service Providers I need to manually update the SP_CLAIM_MAPPING which is not a good practice at all, but this is my only workaround for now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity to carry out the complete Identity and User Store DB migration. Alternatively, you can run it step by step by starting the server with the command line options given below in the following order.

-Dmigrate -DmigrateIdentityDB -Dcomponent=identity

-Dmigrate -DmigrateUMDB -Dcomponent=identity

-Dmigrate -DmigrateIdentityData -Dcomponent=identity

-Dmigrate -DmigrateIdentityDBFinalize -Dcomponent=identity

-Dmigrate -DmigrateUMData -Dcomponent=identity

I guess you used -Dmigrate -DmigrateIdentityDB -Dcomponent=identity to migrate. That should be the issue.

Thanks
Isuraa

Comment: I followed this article: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release. And right before the API changes section, the command stated is "wso2server.bat -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity" for Windows. I am going to try the commands you mentioned separately and see whether this is going to help

Answer (score 0):

What are the roles of admin user. Are they Internal roles or Application roles ?

In 5.2.0 when you create a SP,it will be created a Application role instead of Internal role.

If you cannot see Application roles, then 5 to 5.1.0 migration is not completed correctly.

How did you run the migration script ?
What is the command used ?

Looks like only Identity data are migrated, user data are not migrated.

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I followed this article:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release
And right before the API changes section, the command stated is "wso2server.bat -Dmigrate -Dcomponent=identity" for Windows. So that is the command I used. Do you mean that I should have used "wso2server.bat -Dmigrate" without the identity part? When I create new SP in 5.2.0 indeed the role is Application/SP-name. But the older ones still have Internal/SP-name roles.

Comment: These are some of the roles assigned to the admin:
  Internal/WW-Marketing,Internal/sso-application-dev,Internal/SSO-Application-Localhost,Application/TestIS,Application/test-service-provider,Application/sso,Internal/Account App,Internal/PestPac,Internal/WorkWave-Service,,Application/test2-service-provider

I have a newly created SP and noticed that for them it says Application and not Internal